# nginx htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

how can i convert this to nginx format? Thanks;

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?request=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

In Nginx, Rewriting a request to a .php file will serve the PHP source - there is no `mod_php` that automatically spawns a FastCGI process, instead use PHP-FPM (which I recommended) or [spawn a FastCGI process](http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample).

Assuming you have that set up, you'd want to use the `try_files` directive ([docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files)), something *like*:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?request=$uri&$args;
}
```

Comment: Thank you myanimal but it didnt work. It didnt give any error but its not working. For example without clean urls the url is like that; domain.com/?page=works after i enable clean urls it makes url like this domain.com/works but it doesnt load the page. Any idea?

Comment: What i did and achieved something. I changed the code like that;

`location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?page=$uri&$args;
}`

And this is now works but its not working properly. Now all the links domain.com/projects, domain.com/blog and domain.com/about points to domain.com/?page=projects